# Saving JSON type spark RDD to Cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-streaming, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to store spark RDD to Cassandra table but it's not working.
My RDD is in the form

```
{"id":"04bBGJpwUh","date":"2018-03-26 05:28:25","temp":37,"press":16}
{"id":"pi4Axn3iOd","date":"2018-03-26 05:28:27","temp":49,"press":17}
```

My cassandra table is

```
CREATE TABLE mydata.stations(id text primary key,date text,temp int,press int);
```

Can anyone please help me how to do it? I have tried few examples given but none of them is working.

Comment: Can you please post what you've tried and describe how it's failing?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I have tried                                                               
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark-streaming-consumer-group", Map("hello" -> 5))                                val cass=sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host","127.0.1.1")
                val data=lines.map(_._2)
                val ndata=data.map(Tuple1())
                    ndata.saveToCassandra("mydata","stations")    data rdd is like                     {"id":"04bBGJpwUh","date":"2018-03-26 05:28:25","temp":37,"press":16}

Comment: And nothing is updating in table. I have tried with SomeColumns as well